Rigorous expositions of anti-foundationalism?
Considering how unpopular foundationalism is today, one would assume there would be rigorous defenses of its alternatives.
But where are they? The engagement often seems rather sloppy and doesn't explain well how accepting a non-propositional criterion for justifications isn't, in fact, just a mere reformulation, i.e., hiding a foundational proposition.
It's like I'm searching for arguments and clear expositions and get … metaphors and snarky remarks about René Descartes. Anti-foundationalism appears to be far too obvious for 21st century philosophers.
Does anybody have a suggestion where to start seriously?

IEP, Arguments Against Foundationalism, SEP, Objections to Classical Foundationalism.

@Conifold anti-foundationalism is skepticism about foundational justification + some alternative

On standard use, anti-foundationalism is just the rejection of foundationalism, "the need to ground philosophy". It would be strange to offer alternatives while denying that they are needed, it is enough to argue against the need. However, see Fallibilism and Naturalized Epistemology for some approaches that leave behind justificational concerns foundationalism was meant to address.

@Conifold I don't mean alternative ways to ground philosophy. But alternative ways to have an epistemology or to do philosophy. Otherwise, anti-foundationalism is just skepticism or even anti-philosophy.

Some say that about Wittgenstein and his "therapy", anti-foundationalists are often charged with relativism or even nihilism. However, what philosophy ought to be concerned with is open to debate, including whether traditional grounding is essential to it. I suppose one can see currently popular epistemological naturalism as an alternative of sorts, but it sets aside justificational concerns of traditional epistemology as spurious, not just replaces foundationalist solutions to them with alternative ones.

@Conifold at a first glance, calling epistemological naturalism an alternative to classic foundationalism is remarkable, since it seems naturalism simply became the foundation and they did a bit of rebranding. Also, that article exactly exhibits the problems with the lack of rigor I mentioned. The only thing that's missing are snarky remarks about Descartes.

"Hence, for example, there’s nothing the sciences can tell us that will, or could, inform our answers to the distinctively philosophical questions epistemologists ask" -- I don't know since when importing ideas from the sciences into epistemology was forbidden. It seems manifestly untrue (see Bayesian calculus or the limit concept). So I'd say (from a classical perspective) "inform: yes, but answer: no", since science is based on assumptions that it cannot itself justify.
